# Receiving very small tree in rpart r

Tags: r, rpart

I have about 300,000 records and I am trying to fit the binary categorical explanatory variable "Requested".

I used the following code:

```
require(rpart)
tree <-
  rpart(data=import, method="class",
    formula=Requested ~ 
     p0 + p_r + adow + tk + loy_pres + Sum_Offer_Price
     + Min_Offer_Price + Avg_Offer_Price + Avg_tk_m_p0
     + Min_tk_m_p0 + Avg_p_dis + Min_p_dis)
```

However, the tree came out very simple, with only one split (like an upside-down V).

Does anyone know how to make it more complex? (Include other independent variables on the nodes) Thanks!

Comment: Read the documentation for the `control` argument at `?rpart.control`.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, the splitting criterion is controlled by the `cp` parameter which can be passed directly to `rpart`:

```
rpart( ..., cp = whatever)
```

> cp: complexity parameter.  Any split that does not decrease the
>         overall lack of fit by a factor of ‘cp’ is not attempted.
>         For instance, with ‘anova’ splitting, this means that the
>         overall R-squared must increase by ‘cp’ at each step. The
>         main role of this parameter is to save computing time by
>         pruning off splits that are obviously not worthwhile.
>         Essentially,the user informs the program that any split which
>         does not improve the fit by ‘cp’ will likely be pruned off by
>         cross-validation, and that hence the program need not pursue
>         it.

The default value for `cp` is 0.01. You can keep decreasing cp until you get a tree whose complexity is to your liking (of course this says nothing about how well the tree will generalize to new data; ideally you would tune the `cp` value by cross-validation).

You can also experiment with the values for `minbucket` and the other parameters that you will see in `?rpart.control`.